# Can i show dynamic graphs using d3.js on my pelican website?

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js, pelican

I own a pelican Website and I want to create interactive d3.js visualization on my pelican article that:

1. Reads from a dynamically changing json(Twitter API).
2. Update on a timely basis.
3. Refresh data on push of a Button.
4. Change data using a dropdown menu.

Is there a way to possibly do this given Pelican is a static site generator? I am a little confused on basics so just asking for a little bit of guidance.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: yes

Long answer: It is possible, if you can include javascript in your site and also get data to render from either API call or from the site directly (twitter api is fine). I would still question a bit your choice, as do you really need d3 for this  or is it possible to do with highcharts? D3 can be quite an overkill...

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I wanted to write a tutorial on d3 and thought it would be nice if I can make an interactive visualization that changes with time. I can add JavaScript on the website but don't really know how to handle oauth methods for twitter with pelican....

Comment: Twitter has pretty good introduction how to authenticate to its API: https://dev.twitter.com/oauth/application-only Just keep in mind, that you should implement the calls from the backend (so that the consumer_key and secret could be kept secret)